# Keycloak-js 'init()' not executing in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, keycloak

When I access my app, my Keycloak config is passed to the .init() function to initialize however when I do this, the app stalls and nothing renders on the page, I am not redirected to the keycloak page. The following method is called within index.js before anything is rendered and App should only render upon authentication

```
const initKeycloak = (onAuthenticatedCallback) => {
  _kc.init({
    onLoad: 'check-sso',
    silentCheckSsoRedirectUri: window.location.origin + '/silent-check-sso.html',
    pkceMethod: 'S256',
  })
    .then((authenticated) => {
      if (!authenticated) {
        doLogin();
      }
      onAuthenticatedCallback();
    })
    .catch(console.error);
};
```

When I run, nothing loads and the following is repeated over and over in the logs: `[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...`. I am unable to reach the *.then()* part of the function. If i remove the auth code, page renders as normal. 
 **NOTE:** The keycloak server I am using is a deployed instance and not a local instance. I have checked versions of both keycloak server and keycloak-js and they match

Answer (score 0):

Add this :

```
<html>
   <body>
      <script>parent.postMessage(location.href, location.origin)</script>
   </body>
</html>
```

in your silent-check-sso.html